# spring-integration-smb To read from Samba share

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have to read file from Samba share location for that can I use SPRING-Integration-SMB Spring Integration extension please suggest ?

spring-integration-extensions/spring-integration-smb/

Comment: Yes, you can use that project. Sorry, what is the question then?

Comment: In my project requirement is to read from samba share and have cluster environment so I'm particularly interested in <int-smb:inbound-channel-adapter,session-factory  configuration which will be utilized for transferring files to  and SmbPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter with zookeeper metadata store.

Comment: Good. Sounds like a plan. Let us know if that project has to upgraded to the latest core 4.3

Comment: But Ia m not getting jar in repo for below maven entry.   <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-integration-smb</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>  Also xsd not available  http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/smb/spring-integration-smb.xsd. is there any release version or plan to release in near future ?

Comment: You need `http://repo.springsource.org/libs-snapshot/` repository for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks Artem Bilan for repository but how can I get http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/smb/spring-integration-smb.xsd

Comment: Typically that should be a part of jar. If your IDE is properly configured for Spring Nature, everything should be OK.